Are polynomial hash functions over prime order fields ZK-friendly?
"Traditional" hash functions such as SHA2/SHA3 are not considered ZK-friendly because their translation in the native prime fields of the ZK-proof system leads to a large number of multiplications, resulting in highly inefficient prover performances.
To address this concern, arithmetization-oriented hash functions have been developed (e.g. Poseidon, Anemoi, ...).
However, before their introduction, polynomial hash functions over prime order fields (e.g. Poly1305) already have attracted a lot of attention and are actually deployed in practice (but not in ZK-proof systems to the best of my knowledge).
Is it correct to say that polynomial hash functions over prime order fields (e.g. Poly1305) are arithmetization-oriented?
If so, what makes such functions not adequate for ZK-proof systems?

Poly1305 is not a hash function in the conventional sense.  Instead, it takes a secret key, and if you know the key, it's easy to compute preimages, collisions, etc.  In addition, it uses another cryptographical primitive (e.g. ChaCha20) as part of the secret sauce, and so the ZK-proof would need to cover that as well.


If so, what makes such functions not adequate for ZK-proof systems?

In a zero-knowledge proof, one fundamental thing that a zero-knowledge proof wants is for the prover to be able to show that 'I know a hash preimage to this value'.
Now, Poly1305 isn't a conventional hash function - it takes a secret key.  Here's the issue: with knowledge of the secret key, it is easy to generate preimages for any possible output.  Hence:

If the prover has knowledge of the secret key, then the above proof doesn't actually prove anything (because it doesn't say anything that we didn't already know).

If the prover doesn't have knowledge of the secret key, he wouldn't be able to compute Poly1305 'hashes' in the first place.


